# How to configure a shortcut to open a window accessed by right click on the systray icon?

Tags: command-line, kde, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, window

The application I am referring to is [Turpial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGYQFjAA&url=http://turpial.org.ve/&ei=HAniT-qPIobe9ASbmJ2GCA&usg=AFQjCNHMvq6fCKU-Cxpyew3FtYkxKEL_-Q&sig2=0R4ZsRNyCqznpA2wbE7QmA) and it is a Twitter client.

The problem is to open the window I need to send twits, I have to right click on a systray icon and select an option. In the manual (`man turpial`), I can't find a command to open the 'send twit' window, just the timeline window.

After I open the window and send a twit, the window closes.

I would like configure a global shorcut to open this window and then send my twits.

So, some possibles solutions that I need are:

How do I discover the command in the application that opens the 'send twit' window (when the systray icon right click and option select) and then use it in a terminal? This is probably the better solution.

How to open the 'send twit' window that can be accessed with just a right click (and option select) on the systray icon by the terminal?

How can I enable a shortcut to open this window to send twits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not believe this is going to be possible with Turpial, or indeed any client which has not been designed to work with KDE's Global Shortcuts interface.

However, if you are not bound to Turpial then a client that seems to offer exactly what you are looking for is Choqok. It has a similar lightweight interface to Turpial, however it is a KDE application and, as such, supports KDE's Global Shortcuts.

The action you want in this case would be **Quick Post**, and has a default global key assignment of Ctrl+Meta+T (on my distro, at least) which you can use from anywhere within KDE to immediately present the New Post window.